# How to quote each argument from gnu parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Given some tab-delimited content:

```
Test|One|Two|Three
Again|||Another
```

And a bash function:

```
function print_last() {
  echo "$4"
}
export -f print_last
```

And the `parallel` command: `parallel -C "\|" print_last :::: data.tsv`

My expected output is:

```
Three
Another
```

However, `Another` never prints because the function only receives two arguments for that row of data. This is caused by the empty cells in the tabular data. My data will have blank cells and an varying number of columns.

So, without changing my command to include numbered arguments (`print_last "{1}" "{2}" "{3}" "{4}"`), how can I ensure that blank values are sent to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function is called `print_last` maybe it will be enough to simply get the last element:

```
parallel -C "\|" echo {-1} :::: data.tsv
```

Otherwise abuse that -X will repeat context:

```
parallel -C "\|" -X print_last \"\"{}  :::: data.tsv
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I'll have to read up on the -X switch... seeing that I managed to miss its importance when I RTFM

Comment: Since the above is not really what -X is meant for, it is no surprise you missed it.

Comment: So if I had 3 columns that I wanted to pass as arguments, I'd do `parallel -C "\|" -X my_function \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\" :::: data.tsv`?

Comment: The answer is: I don't need to. The single \"{}\" appears to work for all the arguments

Comment: Bah! Strangely, now parallel ignores all the line endings and passes all the rows as a single string of arguments… ??

Comment: Aha... I needed to add `-N1 -n1` (not sure if both were needed, but it worked with both)

Comment: Still not quite there... now parallel is escaping spaces that are inside the quotes. Is there something I can do to the {} to tell parallel to *not* escape the stuff that's already in quotes? (In the interim, made a glorious hack using bash to removing the backslash in the variable... :'(  )

Comment: So, Ole, is there a way to get parallel to *not* escape the stuff inside the quoted context? It actually puts the backslash inside the argument (in Bash, at least)

Comment: GNU Parallel always escapes replacement of the replacement strings as if they would be see as a single argument directly on the command line. A way to force unescaping is to use `eval`: echo '/ /bin' | parallel eval ls